# Rails PaperClip: How can you convert a public_read file to private?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have recently switched paperclip uploads to use `:s3_permissions => :private`

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Restricting-Access-to-Objects-Stored-on-Amazon-S3

All new uploads are now secured and private.

Now I am trying to secure all previous uploads.

Is it possible to trigger a process that will re-upload as secure with amazon S3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be far easier to update the permissions on all of the objects instead of re-uploading them.

Two ways I can think of to do this:

1. <strike>Paperclip has a [`set_permissions`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip%2FStorage%2FS3:set_permissions) method for attachments using s3 storage, so you could loop through your existing models and call something like `user.avatar.set_permissions(:private)` on each record.</strike>
2. A tool like [s3cmd](https://s3tools.org/s3cmd) would also be well suited to accomplish this. Once installed, a command like this would do it:

`s3cmd setacl --acl-private --recursive --verbose s3://your_bucket/paperclip/path`

UPDATE: `set_permissions` does not do what you would think; it's used when creating the object but does not update the object. Instead, use the paperclip `s3_object` method and then update the object using the aws-sdk api:

`user.avatar.s3_object.acl.put(acl: 'private')`